# How to create a jQuery function that returns another object?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm creating jQuery plugin:

```
$.fn.myGrid = function () {

    return ???;
}
```

I want the return value of `myGrid` to include an add function, so that I can use it in the following way;

```
var grid = $(".myGrid").myGrid();
grid.add();
```

How can I do this? How I have to declare the add function? And what do I have to return in `myGrid` plugin?

I'd also be happy to have something that works like this;

```
$.myGrid.add();
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*One* approach you could use is this;

```
$.fn.myGrid = function () {
    var that = this;

    return {
        add: function () {
            that.after('<h2>Here I am, adding something'); // Note `that` rather than `this`.
        },
        remove: function () {
            that.next().remove();
        }
    };
}
```

It's important to capture the `this` variable, because otherwise the methods on the object you `return` from your `myGrid()` function will not be able to access the jQuery object you invoked `myGrid()` on.

See the code in operation here; http://jsfiddle.net/HpeS8/

Answer (score 0):

Usually, the best convention to write a plugin is something like this :

```
$.fn.pluginName = function(){
    // return the same object to preserve chainability
    // and also apply the plugin's functionality to all the
    // dom elements in this jquery collection
    return this.each(function(i,el){
       // do whatever you want with $(el)
    });
};
```

If you are writing a plugin that returns a value instead of manipulating in some way the current object (say like `width` works), you should return that value instead of the current object reference (`this`) :

```
$.fn.maxWidth = function(){
    var max = 0;
    this.each(function(i,el){
       var w = $(el).width(); 
       if(w > max)
           max = w;
    });
    return max;
};
```

If you want to give the user the possibility to access & modify your plugin functionality, you should definitely preserve chainability (I mean to return `this` and not some other object containing you  plugin's api) and expose the plugin's API to the user through the jQuery element's `data` method.
Here's an example. Lets say that we're making a video player jquery plugin. We want to preserve chainability, but still be able to access the core functions of this plugin.
The **right way** to do this would be something like this :

```
$.fn.videoPlayer = function(){
    var api = {
        play : function(){/*...*/},
        pause : function(){/*...*/},
        stop : function(){/*...*/}
    };  

    return this.each(function(i,el){
       $(el).data('videoPlayerApi',api);
    });
};
```

An usage example which demonstrates my point :

```
$('video')
    // initialising the plugin
    .videoPlayer()
    // the return value is the original jQuery object,
    // so we can still call jQuery methods on it
    .css('opacity',1)
    // select the first video
    .eq(0)
        // access the first video's plugin api
        .data('videoPlayerApi')
            // start only the first video
            .start();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        (function ($) {
             var methods = {
                init: function () {
                  //Initilize
             },
             var add = {
                 //Do something
             }
              $.fn.myGrid= function (method) {
                    if (methods[method]) { 
                        return methods[method].apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1)); 
                   }
                   else if (typeof method === 'object' || !method) { 
                        return methods.init.apply(this, arguments); 
                   }
        else { $.error('Method ' + method + ' does not exist on jQuery.myGrid'); }
    };
})(jQuery);
```

Call like this

```
var grid = $(".myGrid").myGrid();
grid.myGrid("add");
```